# Style.display="block" only for the default div doesn't work at the opening of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, display

So this is my idea: I'm programming my studio's website but in just a page. When you click on a button to go on.. for example, the "Reason why" page, you are not redirect but the page content change! Basically the code is really simple, stuff like this:

```js
function soloprenota() {
  document.getElementById("article1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("article2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("article3").style.display = "none";
}

function soloilnostrosuono() {
  document.getElementById("article1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("article2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("article3").style.display = "none";
}

function soloreasonwhy() {
  document.getElementById("article1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("article2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("article3").style.display = "block";
}
```

Functions are called when you click on the related button on the navigation bar, and everything works how it would do. The problem started when I realized that, at fisrt, when the page gets load no expected actions are given by the user, so it seems there's no way to tell JavaScript to set one of those divs "the dafault".

I've tried in several ways, the most logic may be this one:

```js
if (jQuery.isDefined(soloprenota) || jQuery.isDefined(soloilnostrosuono) jQuery.isDefined(soloreasonwhy)) {
  var examplevar = "examplevaluerlyididntknowwhattomakeitdoesincaseofthis";
} else {
  document.getElementById("article1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("article2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("article3").style.display = "none";
}
```

but never change, at the first load page still shows all the divs.
What would I do to solve this? :/

Comment: What you're trying to achieve on page load ? Should be the first DIV visible only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for short code to use this script and display as you want.

```
function soloprenota(e) {
  var detectid = e;
  if(detectid=="article1"){
  document.getElementById("article1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("article2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("article3").style.display = "none";
  } else if(detectid=="article2"){
  document.getElementById("article2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("article1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("article3").style.display = "none";
  } else if(detectid=="article3"){
  document.getElementById("article3").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("article1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("article2").style.display = "none";
  }
}

//Style Sheet
#article1 {
    display:none;
}
#article2 {
    display:none;
}
#article3 {
    display:none;
}

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li onclick="soloprenota('article1')">soloprenota</li>
    <li onclick="soloilnostrosuono('article2')">soloilnostrosuono</li>
    <li onclick="soloreasonwhy('article3')">soloprenota</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
<div id="article1">article 1</div>
<div id="article2">article 2</div>
<div id="article3">article 3</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I haven't try yet your code but that's not needed: it has gave me the idea of writing "display: none;" for all the divs except for the default one in the css style doc, and it works properly!
Thanks, however. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add `soloprenota();` as the last line of your `<script>`. This will make **soloprenota** as the default.

Check below example.

```js
function soloprenota() {
  document.getElementById("article1").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("article2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("article3").style.display = "none";
}

function soloilnostrosuono() {
  document.getElementById("article1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("article2").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("article3").style.display = "none";
}

function soloreasonwhy() {
  document.getElementById("article1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("article2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("article3").style.display = "block";
}

soloprenota();
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li onclick="soloprenota()">soloprenota</li>
    <li onclick="soloilnostrosuono()">soloilnostrosuono</li>
    <li onclick="soloreasonwhy()">soloprenota</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
<div id="article1">article 1</div>
<div id="article2">article 2</div>
<div id="article3">article 3</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li onclick="soloprenota()">soloprenota</li>
        <li onclick="soloilnostrosuono()">soloilnostrosuono</li>
        <li onclick="soloreasonwhy()">soloprenota</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="article1">article 1</div>
<div id="article2">article 2</div>
<div id="article3">article 3</div>
```